# Sharepoint 2010 wiki include content

Tags: wiki

We have some knowledge that we have organized in a confluence wiki. The content is the form of knowledge reports,that we have matched to wiki pages. But this content has a particularity. Some parts of the report is for internal use, and some other are for public use.

For example, we have a report in which chapters 1 to 5 are public 6 to 8 are private
9 is public and 10 to 20 are private.

We don't know a priori which parts of the report are going to be public or private.

From time to time we receive requests to produce public views of the reports.

To only possible way we found to solve this issue in Confluence is the following (maybe we were taking the wrong path):

- We have created a "mother" private page containing all the private content and afterwards
  created childs with the public content.
- Afterwards in the "mother" private page we have used the "include" confluence macro
  for importing the private child, having a consolidated view of the report.
- When we receive a request for disclosing the public parts of a document we use
  the export capabilities of Confluence and we export only the public pages of 
  a given report.

This approach is cumbersome because if we need to export several reports
we have to do the export one by one, selecting the public pages of each report
and doing the export.

Is out there any way to implement this requirements and solve the problems we have with the wikis of SharePoint 2010?

**EDIT (based on answer):**

What I would need is an easy "include" directive in the syntax of the wiki,
as Confluence has.

*You need to clarify your description. What do you mean when you say "Export"?*

To Export is to generate a Word or PDF file from a page or a set of wiki pages.

*What do you mean when you say you have a Knowledge Report matched to Wiki Pages?*

Ideally, 1 knowledge report = 1 wiki page, but this wiki page is having public and private parts. Private and public versions of the Knowledge report should be produced.

*Are you actually taking the content stored in a Wiki page and then producing some sort of document that you send somewhere?*

Yes.  We have to produce  the public and private versions of the same knowledge report.

*If you just want a way to identify public vs. private pages then add a field to the SitePages library to identify a Wiki page as "public" or "private" and then use that field when you export your report.*

In the same wiki page, i want to identify private parts and public parts.

The only way I see to do it  is having something like that.

Creating the public and private chapter pages

```
        Private Chapter 1 Page
        Private Chapter 2 Page
        Private Chapter 3 page
        Public  Chapter 4 page
        Private Chapter 5 page.
```

and after , creating to index pages, that should be maintained.

```
        Public Index Page
              Includes Public Chapter 4 page
        Private Index Pages
              Includes Chapter 1 Page
              Includes Chapter 2 Page
              Includes Chapter 3 Page
              Includes Chapter 5 Page
```

The wiki should render and display the included pages in the Index Pages (Confluence does it).

Public index Page and Private Index Page, should be able to be exported to word or PDF.

Comment: sharepoint wikis are very simple but it sounds like you should create 2 separate wikis, one for public and one for private

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify your description. What do you mean when you say "Export"? What do you mean when you say you have a Knowledge Report *matched* to Wiki Pages? Are you actually taking the content stored in a Wiki page and then producing some sort of document that you send somewhere?

If you just want a way to identify public vs. private pages then add a field to the SitePages library to identify a Wiki page as "public" or "private" and then use that field when you export your report.

If live users are browsing the Wiki and seeing *public* vs *private* parts of the report as Wiki Pages, then you need to should consider item-level security to secure the private pages.